# Get only numbers from line in file

Tags: c#, filestream

So I have this file with a number that I want to use.

This line is as follows:

`TimeAcquired=1433293042`

I only want to use the number part, but not the part that explains what it is.

So the output is:

```
1433293042
```

I just need the numbers.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: is there other text in the file? is there a separator between the start of the substring you want and the end of the substring?

Comment: You could also consider the use of regular expressions...

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for simple operations like splitting a string on a single character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this and that is to call `Split()` on the string and take the last part.  Like so if you want to keep it as a string:

```
var myValue = theLineString.Split('=').Last();
```

If you need this as an integer:

```
int myValue = 0;
var numberPart = theLineString.Split('=').Last();
int.TryParse(numberPart, out myValue);
```

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps:

- read the complete line
- split the line at the `=` character using `string.Split()`
- extract second field of the string array
- convert string to integer using `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`

Answer (score 4):

```
string setting=sr.ReadLine();
int start = setting.IndexOf('=');
setting = setting.Substring(start + 1, setting.Length - start);
```

Comment: You can use the overload without a length, then it takes the rest.

Answer (score 3):

A good approach to `Extract Numbers Only` anywhere they are found would be to:

```
var MyNumbers = "TimeAcquired=1433293042".Where(x=> char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray();
var NumberString = new String(MyNumbers);
```

This is good when the FORMAT of the string is not known. For instance you do not know how numbers have been separated from the letters.

Comment: `Parameter1=12312313` ?

Comment: @Sinatr: As I said it `Extracts Numbers Only`

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using **split()** function as given below

```
string theLineString="your string";
string[] collection=theLineString.Split('=');
```

so your string gets divided in two parts,
i.e.

1) the part before "="
2) the part after "=".

so thus you can access the part by their index.

if you want to access numeric one then simply do this

```
string answer=collection[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
string t = "TimeAcquired=1433293042";
t= t.replace("TimeAcquired=",String.empty);
```

After just parse.

```
int mrt= int.parse(t);
```

Comment: int mrt = int.Parse("TimeAcquired = 1433293042".Replace("TimeAcquired = ", ""));